# Remove space before chapter title - with KOMA script (scrbook)

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, chapters, koma-script

I am using the KOMA script document class `scrbook`. Is there any way to make the chapter headings appear exactly at the top of the page body just by using KOMA (without using `titlesec`, `fancyhdr`, `fncychap`, ... for they would mess up other things in my documents)? Is there any way to change the space between section heading and the following text?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are we talking about the chapter titles in the document and that KOMA, like the standard class, adds a vertical space before the chapter or do you refer to the header where KOMa can print the current section/chapter one reads in. In case you mean the position of chapters, search for `\chapterheadstartvskip`

Answer (score 14):

**Update**

Since **KOMA-Script version 3.26** you can option `afterindent=false` to avoid the paragraph indentation of the first text line after the chapter title.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterindent=false% <- added
  ]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\blindtext
\end{document}​
```

The result is the same as in the original answer below.

With `afterindent=false` or `afterindent=true` a negative value of `beforeskip` results in a negative skip above the chapter title (needs version 3.26 or newer).

Note: With **KOMA-Script versions 3.22 - 3.25** you have to set `beforeskip` to a negative value to avoid the paragraph indentation in the first text line following the chapter title: `beforeskip=-1sp`. For more information see the documentation or [Adjusting spacing around section/subsection titles with koma-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223524/43317)

---

**Original answer**

With **KOMA-Script Version 3.15 or newer** you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` or `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change the space above or below the chapter title.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\blindtext
\end{document}​
```

Comment: This was the easiest way ever.

Answer (score 11):

The following is probably what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext,showframe}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo} \blindtext \blindtext
\end{document}​
```

Setting `\chapterheadstartvskip` to a no-op removes any vertical skip to set the chapter title on the first line.

[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was loaded just to highlight the text block, while [`blindtext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) provided dummy text.

Comment: There was a change in KOMA-Script version 3.15: now you have to use `\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{}`.

Comment: @Werner, why is there still a little bit of space above the chapter heading, and how would you eliminate it completely?

Comment: @AML: It's most likely as a result of the baseline skip, which leaves room at the top of text so they don't protrude into the descenders of a row of text above it. The easiest would be to try using a small but negative value for the vertical skip; something like `\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{-.2\baselineskip}}`.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing exactly the same problem and I think that this is in fact a problem in KOMA chapter handling. Have a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,
twoside,
scrbook,
fontsize=11pt,
DIV=12,
headings=small,
usegeometry=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

% I would expect that now chapter has no top vskip, just like section
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{}%

\begin{document}
\cleardoubleevenpage
\section*{\usekomafont{chapter}The Section is Correct}
Baz bar.

\clearpage
\chapter*{The Chapter Still Has a Gap Above}
You can see some additional handling in the KOMA scrbook class:\\ 
\textbackslash{}renewcommand*\{\textbackslash{}scr@chapter@beforeskip\}{-2.8\textbackslash{}baselineskip-\textbackslash{}parskip\}\\%
However, I have no idea how to get rid of it and why it is there.
\end{document}
```

I would expect that the chapter* and section* now both have zero top vspace.
If you have a look into scrbook.cls you will see that there is special handling using scr@chapter@beforeskip that is not present for the section commands.

Maybe Markus Kohm could clarify the purpose of this difference and give a hint how to overcome this issue. Here is a post that is somewhat related: [Abstand zwischen Kapitelüberschrift und Kopfzeile](https://komascript.de/node/179?destination=node/179)

[image: MWE that shows Difference between chapter* and section* with zero beforeskip]