# Adjusting spacing around section/subsection titles with koma-script

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script

With the KOMA-script `scrreprt` class the vertical spacing before and after chapter titles can be adjusted the following way:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{70.9pt}}
```

However, I can't find a way to do the same with section, subsection (and, possibly, subsubsection) titles. I know there is the `titlesec` package with the command

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{28.35pt}{0pt}
```

but using KOMA-Script with titlesec gives me the warning "Usage of package `titlesec' together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended". Is there some other way to adjust the vertical spacing around section headings that is compatible with the KOMA-Script classes?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Update**

**KOMA-Script version 3.26** introduces two new keys to `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\RedeclareSectionCommands`: `runin` and `afterindent`. Possible values for both keys are `bysign`, `true` and `false`.

**`runin`:**

This key is only defined for sectioning commands with `style=section`, eg  `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph`, `subparagraph`.

By default **`runin=bysign`** is set. Then the sign of `afterskip` decides if the heading is a runin heading (negative sign) or not (positive value) and the absolute value of `afterskip` is used for the horizontal or vertical skip after the heading. This is the same behavior as explained in the original answer below.

With **`runin=true`** it is a runin heading and the sign of `afterskip` has no meaning anymore. Note that the absolute value of `afterskip` is used as the horizontal skip. So even a negative value of `afterskip` will result in positive horizontal skip.

With **`runin=false`** it is a freestanding heading and the value of `afterskip` is used as vertical skip. Note that with `runin=false` a negative value of `afterskip` results in a negative vertical skip.

**`afterindent`:**

By default

- `afterindent=bysign` is set for `style=section` and `style=chapter`
- `afterindent=true` is set for `style=part` and class `scrartcl`
- `afterindent=false` is set for `style=part` and class `scrbook`

With **`afterindent=bysign`** the sign of `beforeskip` determines if the first line  after the heading uses the paragraph indentation or not. With `afterskip=bysign` the absolute value of `beforeskip` is used as vertical skip above the heading. This is the same behavior as explained in the original answer below.

With **`afterindent=true`** the paragraph indentation is used for the first line following a freestanding heading. With **`afterindent=false`** this first line is not indented. With both `afterindent=true` or `afterindent=false` the value of `beforeskip` is used as the skip above the heading. So a negative value of `beforeskip` results in a negative skip, even for a runin heading.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=.75\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=true,
  %afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1em]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=true,
  %afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1em]{subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Erde}
Der eigentliche Text.\par
Test
\section{Europa}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsection{Italien}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsubsection{Toskana}
Der eigentliche Text.
\paragraph{Florenz}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subparagraph{Dom}
Der eigentliche Text
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer**

It is easy with the new macros `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\RedeclareSectionCommands` of the [KOMA-Script version 3.15](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.75\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=-1em]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=-1em]{subparagraph}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Erde}
Der eigentliche Text.\par
Test
\section{Europa}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsection{Italien}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsubsection{Toskana}
Der eigentliche Text.
\paragraph{Florenz}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subparagraph{Dom}
Der eigentliche Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

`beforeskip`: The absolute value is the vertical space before the heading. If the value is negative the paragraph indent of the text following this heading is suppressed.

`afterskip`: A positive value is a vertical skip below the heading. A negative value activates a run-in heading. Then the absolute value is the horizontal skip.

There is also a command `\RedeclareSectionCommands` to change several section-like commands at once:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.25\baselineskip
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=-1em]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Erde}
Der eigentliche Text.\par
Test
\section{Europa}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsection{Italien}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsubsection{Toskana}
Der eigentliche Text.
\paragraph{Florenz}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subparagraph{Dom}
Der eigentliche Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

### The result is the same as in the original answer.

With **KOMA-Script version 3.14** you have to redefine the original commands (based on a [suggestion by Markus Kohm](http://www.komascript.de/comment/3372#comment-3372)). Note that the original definitions of this commands differ from KOMA-Script version to KOMA-Script version.

```
\documentclass[headings=small]{scrreprt}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}

\makeatletter
 %% check if this are the original definitions
\CheckCommand\section{%
  \scr@startsection{section}{\sectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
\CheckCommand\subsection{%
  \scr@startsection{subsection}{\subsectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subsection
  }%
}
\CheckCommand\subsubsection{%
  \scr@startsection{subsubsection}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subsubsection
  }%
}
 %% redefine
\renewcommand\section{%
  \scr@startsection{section}{\sectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-.5\baselineskip}%
  {.25\baselineskip}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \scr@startsection{subsection}{\subsectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-.5\baselineskip}%
  {.25\baselineskip}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subsection
  }%
}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \scr@startsection{subsubsection}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-.5\baselineskip}%
  {.25\baselineskip}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subsubsection
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Erde}
Der eigentliche Text.\par
Test
\section{Europa}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsection{Italien}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subsubsection{Toskana}
Der eigentliche Text.
\paragraph{Florenz}
Der eigentliche Text.
\subparagraph{Dom}
Der eigentliche Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Notice: The `\RedeclareSectionCommand` thing works even as it is *not* documented in the koma script guide.

Comment: `\RedeclareSectionCommand` *is* documented in the current documentation on CTAN. See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf, section "21.3 Expert commands", page 390

Comment: OK sorry, so I had an old version offline ... :)

Comment: I'm using `v3.19a` and Latex complains that `unknown option beforeskip=-\baselineskip `. It seems it doesn't like the minus, since setting `0.1` works

Comment: with `\titlespacing` I was able to use a negative value afterwards, which essentially brought the next paragraph a little closer. However, here the text is brought on the same line. Can I achieve the same behaviour ?

Comment: AFAIK there must be a number before `\baselineskip`. So you have to  write `beforeskip=-1\baselineskip`.  But with the minus the skip is a horizontal one. So the text starts no the same line. There is no possibility to use a smaller sep between the a section title and the following text as between two normal paragraphs in the text.

Comment: The sep between the section title and the following text is `afterskip` not `beforeskip` and since KOMA-Script 3.26 you can use negative values for `afterskip`. See option `runin` in the answer. So @esdd's comment from 27 '17 at 23:19 is not longer valid.

Comment: @esdd thanks very helpful. Is there any way to do this locally, let's say for one section only?