# How to change space before and after chapter / section etc

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I would like to have the following spacing:

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{13.2pt}{*0}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{13.2pt}{*0}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{13.2pt}{*0}
```

When I'm using titelspacing I'm getting an error due to KOMA-script. I think I have to do it with the following command:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=50sp,
  afterskip=30\baselineskip]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=0\baselineskip,
  afterskip=13.2\baselineskip
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
```

But what values do I have to insert and how can they be calculated? When I use it, there is no change in the spacing.

Moreover, I have recognized that the following part of my code template somehow changes the space before the chapter. Which part of it should I keep or should I throw away everything?

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{215pt}}  % different hack to keep spacing to chapter artwork
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily}

\def\mychpstyleintl{%
{\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\\[100pt]
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.6\linewidth}}
\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}}
\rightline{{%
\sffamily%
\fontseries{bx}%
\fontshape{n}%
\fontsize{100}{120}%choose baselineskip to be 1.2 times font size
\selectfont
\thechapter}}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}\\[300pt]
\end{tabular}
}}
```

Comment: Since you're using KOMA-script, there's probably a way to do this without the `titlesec` package, though I don't know how myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

**KOMA-Script version 3.26** provides `afterindent` as new option for `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and `\RedeclareSectionCommands`, see the documentation or [Adjusting spacing around section/subsection titles with koma-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223524/43317).

So now you can use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=50pt,% <- changed
  afterskip=30pt,
  afterindent=false% <- added
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=0pt,% <- changed
  afterskip=1.2pt,
  afterindent=false%<- added
 ]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

to get the same result as in the original answer below.

---

**Original answer**

Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. There is the command `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the space before and after a section title. But use the correct units ...

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-50pt,
  afterskip=30pt
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=1.2pt
 ]{section,subsection,subsubsection}
```

Note that the `beforeskip` must be lower than 0 to remove the par indent for the text directly following after the section command. So you have to use `-1sp` that is nearly `0pt`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-50pt,
  afterskip=30pt
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=1.2pt
 ]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

The line

```
 \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{215pt}}
```

has the same effect as

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-215pt
]{chapter}
```

So you have to decide if you want `50pt` or `215pt` space before your chapter title??

Comment: Such a nice suggestion... Wow